Darknet Yolov4-tiny (Grayscale Input) to Tensorflow Weights, Conversion
TL;DR:
1-channel TF model behaves differently than 3-channel one. Both converted successfully from Darknet -> TF, but 1-channel model does not perform as well as before conversion.
Task at hand and statements:
I have two trained yolov4-tiny darknet weight files (.weights), other has grayscale input (1-channel) and other has color input (3-channel). I am converting both of the weight files to Tensorflow checkpoint format with a common repository (for this task) found from:
https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite.git
Performance of both models has been tested by c++ opencv readNetFromDarknet() and with Python equivalent. Both models are inherently trained with grayscale images and operate on grayscale images. Input for 3-channel model is just grayscale image scaled to 3-channels.
Python version: 3.10.11
TF version: 2.10.1
Problem statement:
Weight file with color input converts fine and works well afterwards when loaded with tf.keras.Models.load_model(X), however when converting grayscale input weight file, performance of the model when loaded with Tensorflow, drops drastically, and I mean detections are bad or non-existent in the most obvious cases where model with color input works perfectly. Note worthy thing is that boxes are not out of place, meaning when detections are found they are about at the correct position, but for example width and height might be off.
I am aware of the common problems with this repository (hardcoded stuff, etc.) and changed parameters accordingly for each conversion/model loading, and no errors what so ever happens during conversion nor the model loading.
I have confirmed Input layers:

Grayscale: (None,640,640,1)
Color: (None,640,640,3)

Test images (for performance testing) are loaded with opencv-python, and their validity has also been reviewed, even if error occurs if data with wrong dimension is being inserted to the input layer.
Architectures excluding Input layer are the same, confirmed with model.summary().
I have noted that architecture produced by model.summary() to a 3-channel model that I have converted few **years ** ago with different TF version is somewhat different. Some tile layers seem to be missing. Also some of the tf operations are with a different name but that might be just the different TF version.
Old Color model:
 tf_op_layer_Sigmoid (TensorFlo  (None, 40, 40, 3, 2  0          ['tf_op_layer_split_3[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)                      )

 tf_op_layer_Tile/multiples (Te  (5,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice[0][0]
 nsorFlowOpLayer)                                                ']

 tf_op_layer_Sigmoid_3 (TensorF  (None, 20, 20, 3, 2  0          ['tf_op_layer_split_4[0][0]']
 lowOpLayer)                    )                       )

New Grayscale model:
 tf.math.sigmoid (TFOpLambda)   (None, 40, 40, 3, 2  0           ['tf.split_3[0][0]']
                                )

---tile layer missing here---


 tf.math.sigmoid_3 (TFOpLambda)  (None, 20, 20, 3, 2  0          ['tf.split_4[0][0]']
                                )

I am quite stuck at the moment. Any help?
Some trial and errors:

Playing with Yolov4-tiny Head decoding block -> No changes even in cases where model was able to be loaded (wrong dimensions in decode raise errors)
Older 3-channel model (already converted Darknet -> TF years ago) referenced earlier, works perfectly when loaded the same way than the new models

Resolution:
I printed layers with their shapes from c++ as models worked there and I was left wondering that shapes are completely different. The very first convolutional layer was not downsized at all. I inspected the .cfg file that Darknet uses to parse the model and there was a line on the first convolutional layer "size=3stride=2". Size is parsed correctly but stride is not, and it defaulted to 1, which makes first convolutional layer in shape of (640,640,32) instead of expected (correct) (320,320,32). When I loaded weights to the correct architecture of course it performed badly as it is trained with another layout. I suspect I have trained 3-channel model with a .cfg that did not have this error and that is why it works perfectly.

Which Darknet repo did you use?  Because the AlexeyAB repo has been abandoned since July 2021.  On the newer fork, we've made lots of fixes over the last few years, including a push about a year ago to better support single-channel images.  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet

Yeah I used the original one. Sadly all my models have been trained with that, so I must be able to convert specifically those models. But thank you for the suggestion, I definitely take a look.

@Stéphane By the way, can you elaborate what is the problem with grayscale images with original darknet and what was fixed exactly in the new repo?

Many places in the code where the number of channels was hard-coded to 3, improper handling of channels, assumptions that all images have 3 channels.
